# Setting Window Icon tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to change the icon on my tkinter window and I think my problem is stemming from my lack of understanding classes.

I want to know why:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = r'stockIcon.gif')
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, img)

root.mainloop()
```

works perfectly. But:

```
import tkinter

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = r'stockIcon.gif')
        self.root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, img)
        self.root.mainloop()

test = Test()
```

throws `NameError: name 'root' is not defined`. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: the error is telling you exactly what the problem is. You've defined `self.root` but not `root`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to access `root` through `self.root`

change:

```
self.root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, img)
```

to:

```
self.root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self.root._w, img)
```

Comment: Wow that's it. Thank you so much! I feel really dumb now.

Comment: No problem, getting used to Object Oriented Programming takes time.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid access the private `_w` attribute of `root`?

Comment: @phoenix Yes: `str(self.root)`. Maybe even just `self.root` as `tkinter` converts all things handed off to Tk/Tcl into strings anyway as Tcl is a quite „stringly typed“ language. :-)